# How to find missing values(number) in a sequence(table) with php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to write a query to show the missing numbers in a database table(book), it can be one or several missing numbers.

[image]

Notice the values 1, 5, 7, 8, and 10 are missing from the sequence, I try but non of my solution works. Now I'm looking out if some one can help me, i´m new at this so .

***EDIT:*** mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT number FROM book
WHERE number BETWEEN 1 and (SELECT max(id) FROM book)
AND number NOT IN (SELECT id FROM book)
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kowts

Comment: include what you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This PHP should do the trick (assuming `$numbers` is an array containing the numbers from your database).

```
$compare_array = range(1, max($numbers));
$missing_values = array_diff($compare_array, $numbers);
```